# Print/Return JSON from Lex to the End point of API Gateway using Lambda

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, integration

I want the below JSON (especially the Slot value "Rose") to be printed/returned on to the API end point URl (using API Gateway), whenever the Lambda function is invoked. Could you please help give me the lambda function code in Nodejs, or python, please?.

```
{
  "dialogState": "Fulfilled",
  "intentName": "Shopping",
  "message": "What xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "slotToElicit": null,
  "slots": {
    "Product": "Rose"
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a homework. Please share the code that you have already written and post back here when you have a specific problem that you are struggling to solve.

Comment: I do not have any code already(hence seeking help). I am new to AWS. Trying to build a chat bot in AWS lex.

Comment: Perhaps a default Lambda in nodejs( But what i want is not the key value. I simply want the slot value used by the lex's current intent instead of the below : 
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, "Key value is "+ event.key1);
};

Comment: import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps('Hello World!')
    }    
def elicit_slot(intent_name, slots, slot_to_elicit, message):
    return {
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'ElicitSlot',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'slots': slots,
            'slotToElicit': slot_to_elicit,
            'message': message
        }
    }

I want current slot values used to be printed instead of Hello World in the API Gateway